# Django ошибка: "NOT NULL constraint failed"

Tags: python, django

У меня есть модель отслеживаний. К ней привязан пользователь (user должен быть необязательным полем), но когда я пытаюсь сохранить данные, то мне выдаётся следующая ошибка:

```
IntegrityError at /admin/profiles/tracking/220/change/
NOT NULL constraint failed: profiles_tracking.user_id
```

models.py

```py
class Tracking(models.Model):
    products = JSONField(default={'items': []}, verbose_name='Товары')
    categories = JSONField(default={'items': []}, verbose_name='Категории')
    notification_sms = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Уведомления смс')
    notification_email = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Уведомления email')
    user = models.ForeignKey('account.CustomUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Пользователь')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Подписка')
    subscription_time_start = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Начало отслеживания')
    subscription_time_end = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Конец отслеживания')
```

Comment: миграции созданы и выполнены?

Comment: Извиняюсь, я сглупил и забыл про миграции, спасибо)